# What is the meaning of this following piece of code({:.3f}) used in a Decision Tree tutorial?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am following a DecisionTree tutorial, and in the step that involves printing out the results, the piece of code `{:.3f}` is used and I am trying to understand its meaning and use. For some reason, googling it has yielded nothing. I am using Spyder with Python 3.6.

```
print("Accuracy on training set: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

Comment: Search for "Python string formatting". It's just a way of telling the string parser what format `tree.score` should be converted into.

Comment: `print("check this out: {:.3f}".format(0.2))` : check this out: 0.200